# Which version of hinge loss to use in GAN?

Tags: loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I have read about hinge loss and how they work in SVM and GAN. However, I am confused about its equation for the discriminator in GAN. I have seen the loss implemented in two versions.

This is the first version from [BigGAN](https://github.com/MingtaoGuo/BigGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/ops.py#L5) implementation in github:

```py
def Hinge_loss(real_logits, fake_logits):
    D_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.minimum(0., -1.0 + real_logits)) - tf.reduce_mean(tf.minimum(0., -1.0 - fake_logits))
    G_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(fake_logits)
    return D_loss, G_loss
```

The second one is in [neuralgym](https://github.com/JiahuiYu/neuralgym/blob/master/neuralgym/ops/gan_ops.py) package implementation:

```py
def gan_hinge_loss(pos, neg, value=1., name='gan_hinge_loss'):
    """
    gan with hinge loss:
    https://github.com/pfnet-research/sngan_projection/blob/c26cedf7384c9776bcbe5764cb5ca5376e762007/updater.py
    """
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        hinge_pos = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.relu(1-pos))
        hinge_neg = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.relu(1+neg))
        scalar_summary('pos_hinge_avg', hinge_pos)
        scalar_summary('neg_hinge_avg', hinge_neg)
        d_loss = tf.add(.5 * hinge_pos, .5 * hinge_neg)
        g_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(neg)
        scalar_summary('d_loss', d_loss)
        scalar_summary('g_loss', g_loss)
    return g_loss, d_loss
```

So, basically the first one uses the min function, while the second one uses relu (max function). I have compared the results of both, they give the same results in terms of numerical results but the second version results in better quality images.

The question is, which is the correct hinge loss? And if both are correct, then why the second version gives a better output?

Thanks in advance!